# The integers 1 through 9 are arranged

Tags: divisibility, recreational-mathematics

The integers 1 through 9 are arranged as follows on a rectangular keypad:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Consider the 6-digit palindromes (numbers that have the same sequence of digits from right to left as left to right) formed by going back and forth across each row, column or diagonal; for example, going back and forth across the top row we form `123321`, as well as `321123`. One diagonal yields `159951` and `951159`, and the second column gives us `258852` and `852258`.

a) Explain why each of the numbers obtained as described above is divisible by 111. Your explanation should not involve going through each case; instead, your goal is to find a property that these numbers share, that ensures divisibility of 111.

b) Can you generalize your result above? Can you have keypads with different combinations of numbers that retain this property? What happens if you consider numbers in a different base?

Comment: Hint: try expressing the successive ciphers in a row, column or diagonal as $x$, $x+d$, $x+2d$ ...

Answer (score 2):

For the first question note that your numbers are of the form $abccba=$ where $b=a+1$ and $c=a+2$ then we have it is equal to:

$a×100000+b×10000+c×1000+c×100+b×10+a×1=$

$a(100000+1)+b(10000+10)+c(1000+100)=$

$a (100001)+b (10010)+c (1100)=$

$a×100001+a×10010+10010+a×1100+2×1100=$

$a(100001+10010+1100)+(10010+2200)=$

$a (1001×111)+(110×111)= $

$111 (a×1001+110)$

and then $111$ divides the numbers.

I think you can try the second part analyzing how this was solved, hope it helps.

Edit: I meant to say the first case you want to solve and I wanted you to try the column and diagonal case based in this approach.

Comment: This solves the “row” case. With a small change in your formulas you can also solve the “column” and the “diagonal” cases in one blow.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I meant I wa solving the first case and letting the other two as exercise because it is analogous

Comment: @Dario but it would good to see some effort from the original poster of the question.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I only showed the row case.

Comment: @Joffan Agreed. My comment was meant for the OP. I see now that I haven’t made it clear enough. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $10^{2k+1}+1$ (k>=0) is always divisible by 11.